# nginx is not serving go static files

Tags: docker, go, nginx

My app structure is like this:

```
.
├── src
│   └── some go files
├── templates
├── static
    |── images
    |── js
    └── styles
```

And here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

CMD ["go", "run", "src/cmd/main.go"]
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"


services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - todo_pg_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=todo
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - pgsql

    
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 801:801
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf


volumes:
  todo_pg_db:
```

And here is the `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 801;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        charset utf-8;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @backend;
        }

        location @backend {
            # client_max_body_size 10m;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that nginx can't find static files.
Here is some example logs:

```
open() "/usr/src/app/static/styles/bootstrap.min.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

But there is such directory.
when I exec to my docker container using this commad: `sudo docker exec -it todo_app_1 bash`.
Then I cat contents of the file, and it works fine!!!

```
cat /usr/src/app/static/styles/bootstrap.min.css
# output: file content...
```

I don't know what is wrong in here.
What am I missing?

Comment: nginx is running from a different image, it's not going to have the source of your Go app included. (Also don't use filename arguments to `go run`. If you want to use `run` and have it work correctly with modules, use `go run .`, but it would be better to not recompile the app ever time the container started)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I sync their files? Can you give me a keyword so I can search for it?

Comment: You can mount the static files as a volume in the nginx container in the docker-compose file

Comment: @paltaa I have posted an answer can you check it pls? nginx is serving my static files correctly now.

Comment: file looks good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that using `volumes`:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 801:801
  volumes:
    - ./static:/var/www
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and in `nginx.conf`:

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www;
}
```